# AngularJS watch variable in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-local-storage

I have one problem.
I'm using [Angular localStoragee](http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html) module to store settings, which i set in controller with:

```
localStorageService.set('localStorageKey','Add this!');
```

It's working very well but how can i watch localStorageKey for changes in directive, which takes it's value as a parameter?

I tried something like:

```
.directive('fooBar', function(localStorageService){
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){

        var unit = localStorageService.get('localStorageKey');
        $watch('unit', function(){
            console.log(unit);
        });

    }

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            value: '@dataValue'
        },
        replace: true,
        link: linker
    }
});
```

But no luck, i don't think i can watch variables like this. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return localStorageService.get('localStorageKey');
}, function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```